# What are the extensibility options for VS 2022 for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

Trying to find information on VS 2022 for Mac extensibility but online docs only refer to the earlier MonoDevelop ide extensions pre 2022. On the VS 2022 for Mac blogs I cannot seem to add comments to get some info as the comment section is closed.

There is also a new easier Visual Studio Extensibility approach in the works for the PC version, but no info if that is intended for the Mac and to converge with that.

Can anyone shed any light on how to do IDE extensions now on the 2k22 Mac VS and what the roadmap looks like?

Comment: The MonoDevelop IDE extensions information is likely still relevant, although the APIs may have changed in Visual Studio for Mac 17.x. I have some basic extensions examples - https://github.com/mrward/vsmac-extensibility-samples - and also have more in depth examples elsewhere on my github repo. In general the documentation is lacking, or refers to MonoDevelop. There is no roadmap.

Comment: @MattWard Oh wow, many thanks! Mac 17.x refers to the "2022" new version, right?

Comment: @MattWard I am developing components to help MS devs start adopting Algorand , including compilers based on Roslyn and VS IDE extensions. I was trying to figure out a way of contacting someone involved in this VS for Mac project. I will need to add the VS for Mac support soonish, so I am turning my attention to research things in advance now. Is it also possible in VS for Mac to extend to include new project templates like in the VS VSIX? Any help appreciated... Any chance I can email you on the lastexitcode domain? or some other method.

Comment: @Frank Yes, Visual Studio 2022 is Visual Studio v17.*, VS2019 is v16.*, and VS2017 is v15.*. The Wikipedia entry for Visual Studio has a convenient table of names and versions - see [History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio#History).

Comment: @JonathanDodds Nice one, Jonathan. Cheers.

Comment: An extension can include its own project templates. The Meadow extension is one third party extension that does that - https://github.com/WildernessLabs/VS_Mac_Meadow_Extension/blob/main/VS4Mac_Meadow_Extension/Properties/Manifest.addin.xml#L26

Comment: There is no large ecosystem for Visual Studio for Mac extensions, compared with Visual Studio on Windows, so documentation is limited. There are only 2 third party extensions - MFractor and Meadow. The other extensions are from people on the Visual Studio for Mac team. You can contact me via email if you need help, email is matt.ward at microsoft. Or on twitter 'lastexitcode' - Dominique who works on the Meadow extension usually chats to me on twitter about VS Mac.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant Matt many thanks. I will email you now just to establish contact (and so that you can delete the comment above if you want), though I will be turning my attention to this task more fully sometime in the coming weeks/months.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's exactly the situation and you only have a few options,

- VS for Mac feedback https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/report-a-problem?view=vsmac-2022 (What you should focus)
- Gitter MonoDevelop https://gitter.im/mono/monodevelop (though this one should be dedicated to the deprecated MonoDevelop project)

Note that VS for Mac has changed so much in the past few years, so I don't think it an easy task to keep extensibility stable.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post on getting started with [Extending Visual Studio for Mac 2022](https://christianhelle.com/2023/03/extending-vsmac.html). I used a similar example extension from the [Extending Visual Studio for Mac Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/mac/extending-visual-studio-mac-walkthrough?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5004822) article from MSDN and updated certain parts so it works in Visual Studio for Mac 2022

Some of the MonoDevelop guides are still correct as Visual Studio for Mac is still pretty much a re-branded MonoDevelop